# Which of these statements implies the other?

Tags: real-analysis, proof-verification

$$\text{(i)} \forall \epsilon>0 \exists N \in \mathbb{N} \forall n \in \mathbb{N}: n > N \implies |x_n| < \epsilon $$

$$\text{(ii)} \exists N \in \mathbb{N} \forall \epsilon>0   \forall n \in \mathbb{N}: n > N \implies |x_n| < \epsilon $$

I have to give a "brief" reason.

I have said $(ii) \implies (i)$
Since we have found an $N$ that works for all $\epsilon>0$

I need to find an example of a sequence that holds for one but not  the other. But I cant seem to figure one out.

Comment: You are correct: Given some $N$ which works for (ii), we know it works for  whatever $\varepsilon$ you throw at it. Thus, this $N$ works for (i).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Let $x_n=1/n$. Then (i) holds but (ii) does not: given any $N$, choosing $\epsilon=1/(N+2)$ violates (ii).